# Boostrap navigation links make awkward jump on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have a Bootstrap navigation bar which is as you can see more or less customized with CSS. But when I hover over the `<a>` tags these links jump left or right. Does anyone have an idea what's the problem and how to solve it? Down below is a code and fiddle.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nJfAZ/3391/

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
        <li><a href="kolekcija.html">Collection</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.nav > li > a {
  margin-left: -2em; 
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
  border-color: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap applies a border by default, and when you remove it it causes the jump. Just change the color to transparent instead:

```
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nJfAZ/3395/)**